# How to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\prod^{n-1}_{k=1} \left( \frac{x^2}{n^2}-2(\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)-1)\right)$

Tags: limits, hyperbolic-functions

I am looking to show that:

$$\sinh(x)/x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\prod^{n-1}_{k=1} \left( \frac{x^2}{n^2}-2(\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)-1)\right)\tag{1}$$
which I know to be true from other means.

I have tried using that:
$$ \sinh(x)/x= \prod^\infty_{n=1}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2 \pi^2}\right)$$
but naively expanding the $\cos(\ldots)$ in (1) doesn't work. Does anyone know the best way to approach this?

Comment: In order to reduce the clutter I suggest you to write the initial product as $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{x^2}{n^2}+4\sin^2\frac{\pi k}{2n}\right)$$ then exploit Chebyshev polynomials of the first/second kind.